# UX Feedback format?

Tags: feedback

most of the time clients come to me and ask to give UX feedback on their products, most of which are 10-20 years old. At first they ask to give a report. Is there any standard method of giving feedback report?

Comment: I think it would make sense to ask what the intent of the feedback is, because if it is driven by user complaints, then perhaps you can focus more on research to uncover the underlying problem. If it is a usability issues, then it is more about looking at analytics and user testing where the interface design problems might be. If it is about new product features or improvements, then you need to look at what's out there and come up with something new or different from the competitors. Providing them with a bunch of deliverable without a clear intent won't result in actionable outcomes.

Comment: Yeh you are right, but most of the cases i come across the product owners are not aware what they want, at that cases what am i supposed to do?

Comment: In that case you should work with them to tease out exactly what they want to achieve (some people are better at coming up with problems, others are better at coming up with solutions, find out which type they are), otherwise you'll end up with a bunch of documents and they will still not be clear about what they need or want you to do. Which is fine if you are just providing a service to review their product, but not much point if they need actionable feedback on their products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a good idea to ask the product owner what is the purpose of this UX feedback? You could organise a workshop with him and let him answer these questions:

1. What is the current state of user experience from the user prospective?
2. What research do we have, and what do we need to gather?
3. What are user tasks and goals?
4. Identifying users?
5. What are the user segments?

If he doesn't know any of these then start working on couple of things:

1. Personas
2. Empathy Mapping
3. Qualitative Analysis
4. Short Field study

etc. It all depends on how much PO know about the Product or if he/she has any goals.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a website, try looking at their Google Analytics. This is one thing I do a lot just to convince the client about the depth of the UX problem and an instant feedback about UX problems with screenshots. Let's say you look at userflow in Google Analytics and found that their drop off rate is heavy at one particular funnel, try matching this with user testing videos.

In a nutshell, I follow this:

- User Persona
- Create a Google Analytics content report
- Decide which type of test to conduct and do one as an example.
- Document about findings

Create a final document which combines all of the above. I'm sure the product managers or the clients looking at these get a solid evidence of what needs to be done. All of the above if worked in a smart way wont take more than a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

I generally do

- **Heuristic evaluation** on the product

---

- I do **user research** and depict the data as feedback report

---

- I do **competitor analysis** in some cases.

---

but most of the cases I come across the product owners are not aware what they want, at that cases what am I supposed to do?

but I am not sure which of these to be included at times.or any other things I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the standards way is to conduct a **usability study**. That includes how well Apple HCI guidelines and other International guidelines are being followed.